# Why is Vue not defined here?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-resource

Why am I getting Vue is not defined as an error here:

```
export default {
    state: {
        projects: {
            loading: true,
            failed: false,
            lookups: [],
            selectedId: 0
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        loadingProjectLookups (state, payload) {
            state.projects.loading = true;
            state.projects.failed = false;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        loadProjectLookups (context) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                // VUE NOT DEFINED HERE:
                Vue.http.get('https://my-domain.com/api/projects').then((response) => {
                    context.commit('updateProjectLookups', response.data);
                    resolve();
                },
                response => {
                    context.commit('failedProjectLookups');
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my vue config:

```
'use strict';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');


/* plugins */ 
Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueResource);


/* stores */
import importPageStore from './apps/import/import-page-store';


/* risk notification import */
import ImportApp from './apps/import/import-app.vue';
if (document.querySelector("#import-app")) {
    var store = new Vuex.Store(importPageStore);
    new Vue({
        el: '#import-app',
        store,
        render: h => h(ImportApp)
    });
}
```

My understanding is that Vue is defined globally and I cannot see why it is not defined. If I add `import Vue from 'vue'` to my store then I get a message that http is not defined. So I need to work out why Vue appears not to be available globally as I shouldn't have to do this.

I am using webpack to build my vue components. I have other pages rendered using this methodology and they work just fine. But this one does not? I am honestly stumped as to why as I cannot see any differences. The page renders and works. I can see that Vue is working. How can it be undefined?

Comment: Is `document.querySelector('#import-app')` condition truthy? Do you have an element with an id `import-app` when this script is running?

Comment: Yes I do, the app does indeed render and run. However a reference to `Vue` is not defined.

Comment: Oh I see, in your component, you are using `Vue.http`, you will need to import `Vue` in that file, or just use `this.$http` instead.

Comment: I've tried that and if I use this.$http I get `_this.$http is undefined`.

Comment: The render function was using `ImportAppStore` instead of `ImportApp` and the `store` variable should take `ImportPageStore` instead of `importPageStore`

Comment: Hi, sorry those are just typos from obfuscating my company name from the code. Many apologies there!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164191/discussion-between-ricky-and-jon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a component, you can use `this.$http`, however, in your store you will need to import `Vue` every time.

What you can do, is create a `service` folder and import Vue there. Then just reference your service in the store file.

There's an example here https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/85

Which suggests something like this:

/services/auth.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {

  authenticate(request) {

      return Vue.http.post('auth/authenticate', request)
        .then((response) => Promise.resolve(response.data))
        .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));

    },

    // other methods 
}
```

In your store file:

```
import { AUTHENTICATE, AUTHENTICATE_FAILURE } from '../mutation-types'
import authService from '../../services/auth'

export const authenticate = (store, request) => {

  return authService.authenticate(request)
    .then((response) => store.dispatch(AUTHENTICATE, response))
    .catch((error) => store.dispatch(AUTHENTICATE_FAILURE, error));

}

// other actions
```

---

This is how [VueResource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) extends `Vue` prototype.

```
Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
        // [...]
        $http: {
            get() {
                return options(Vue.http, this, this.$options.http);
            }
        },
       // [...]
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this also apply when `VueResource` is accessed from within a store? Though I have just finished working on a page that is almost exactly the same as this one and that works. Vue is not undefined. Something seems to be different for this page. I must stress that the app does run/ It can access the store. But for some reason when I call the action that loads my project Vue is undefined. Also if I type `Vue` into my browser console it is undefined where as it's not on my other page...

Comment: It is possible that in your other project `Vue` is exposed in the global object, try and check if it is exposed through your `webpack.config`.

Comment: As a side note, it should not be exposed in the global object, every component should be called within the main `Vue` instance, there is usually a `main.js` file that defines this 'main' instance.

Comment: Okay, I'm not aware of this pattern. I am defining a Vue instance per page using the document selector to work out which app to render. The pages are separate MVC pages though.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were going for a Vue SPA. If you are integrating Vue into something like ASP.NET, you can create an instance per page. I'm afraid I need more information in order to help. I'll move this discussion to chat.

Comment: Absolutely stellar! Many thanks for your help. A separate link to Vue outside of the webpack bundle was causing the discrepancy between pages. Import Vue into my store has fixed this though I will definitely abstract my API calls out into their own files.

Answer (score 0):

VueResource handles the promise itself. Thus, you don't need to wrap the requests in promises. You can use Promise.all() later. But I don't see multiple requests so you just use the get request.

Reference: [Using promise in vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/309)

I hope, this would solve your issue with that error.